# unable to get the value of href from a tag using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying fetch the `href` value in an `<a>` with a class of "title". The result here should be the path `"../../images/packages2/agra1.jpg"` but somehow it's not working. Here is my HTML:

```
  <div id="packgeImages">
        <ul>
<li><a class="title" href="../../images/packages2/agra1.jpg" rel="shadowbox" title=""><img src="../../images/packages2/agra1thumb.jpg" alt="thumb1" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
  var $title = $('.title').attr("href");
```

Then I am using alert to check the results.. but somehow it seems blank.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note that a `$` prefix for variables in JavaScript is usually reserved for denoting variables which contain a jQuery object. Your `$title` contains a plain old string. Or at least it would, if your code functioned as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Use `first` when finding an element based on a class, as there may be more than one element with the same class name.

```
var $title = $('.title:first').attr("href");
```

This works:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xs9AC/2/

**Edit for your comment:**

```
var arr = new Array(); // Create the array

// Loop through each anchor
$(".title").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).attr("href"));
});

// Loop through the populated array
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i]);
};
```

Comment: actually i want to append values from a table and add it dynamically to the multiple links with same class. so i can't get the exact path.

Comment: I wanted to know how to grab the href values, i am not able to get the values first in a variable.. maybe i should put up this question in more detail. thanks for the help.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028293/adding-href-attribute-dynamically-with-data-from-a-table-using-jquery

Comment: @designerNProgrammer Please close this question then to save confusion.