# adding href attribute dynamically with data from a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am stuck here, actually wanted to **change the href values of the a tag with rel=shadowbox property** of a items in list , where the data is read from the table on the page..
here is my html code

```
   <div id="packgeImages">
        <ul>
<li class="title"><a href="" rel="shadowbox"><img src="../../images/packages2/agra1thumb.jpg" alt="thumb1" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is my jquery code to capture the paths from grid and then append to the class .title

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $title = $('.title').attr("href"); //Unable to capture this
        $('#fullImageGridView tr').each(function (i) {
            if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skips first row
            var bigSizeImagePath = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
          //  alert(bigSizeImagePath);
            $title.eq(i - 1).append(bigSizeImagePath);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I guess the appending is not working fine, the changes should be made linke this `$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")`
I mean changing the attribute of href and not appending the values?? right?

Comment: can you check $('.title').length this will be helpful

Comment: It should be $('.title a').attr('href'). title is your `li` and `a` is inside title.

Comment: ok i did that and still not appended, and now the alert shows only first record, rest are skipped i guess.:(

Answer (score 2):

```
var $title = $('.title a').attr("href");
```

Comment: Looks like you're not targeting the a element

Comment: when i remove this line  $title.eq(i - 1).append(bigSizeImagePath); the  alert shows all the paths but when i add the line, it only reads the first one.??

Answer (score 2):

```
$('[rel=shadowbox]').attr('href', yourValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

modified code ::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $title = $('.title [rel="shadowbox"]').attr("href"); //Unable to capture this
        $('#fullImageGridView tr').each(function (i) {
            if (!this.rowIndex) return; // skips first row
            var bigSizeImagePath = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
          //  alert(bigSizeImagePath);
            $title.eq(i - 1).append(bigSizeImagePath);
        });
    });
</script>
```